# Why are my overloaded functions not seen by a subclass

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I have a base class Base which provides a series of load functions, which read saved settings from a file. For example

```
void Base::load(QWidget *w);
virtual void Base::load(QTableWidget *t); // note this is declared virtual
void Base::load(QLineEdit *le);
```

Where Base::load(QWidget *w) will typically be called by a subclass on a high level widget. That routine will find the child widgets of the input widget (by type), and call the appropriate load routine on those. The overloading works as expected. 
So in a subclass OkSubClass, I typically do a load like this:

```
void OkSubClass::load(void)
{
 load(myMainWidget);
 load(myOtherHighLevelWidget);
}
```

All is good - anything that is a child of either widget gets loaded.

Now I have a subclass of Base which needs to load things for a table slightly differently. It declares

```
virtual void ProblemSubClass::load(QTableWidget *t) ;
```

I also have some widgets used by this class that inherit a form class; e.g.

```
class myWidget: public QWidget, public MyForm { ... };
```

and ProblemSubClass has a member variable

```
myWidget *_myMainWidget;
```

now in the routine ProblemSubClass::load(void), I try to do the following:

```
ProblemSubClass::load(void)
{
  load(_myMainWidget);
}
```

it complains that it can't convert _myMainWidget to a QTableWidget *. Which surprises me, because I thought that ProblemSubClass should be able to see the load(QWidget*) member function.
If I directly call the base class function, it works.

```
ProblemSubClass::load(void)
    {
      Base::load(_myMainWidget);
    }
```

But I don't understand why it doesn't if I don't. Please enlighten me!

Comment: Instead of describing your code in words, do it in *code*. It's much easier to understand what's happening if you take some time to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Name hiding, see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#hiding-rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you write `using Base::load;` somewhere in the declaration of the child class, that child class will not be able to see the other `load` functions declared in the base class.

It's one of those parts of C++ that appears odd at first.

Comment: well there you go. first time I've stumbled upon it in..erm.. dare I say how long..

Comment: I will confess I've never really understood *why* C++ works this way.

Comment: does this only apply to overloaded functions? or is it the fact that it's virtual?

Comment: The second comment under the question explains it well.